# Handling StaleStateException

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate in my Project. I have two methods which get called concurrently and they try to update the same rows. In the following code the two methods are **updateSessionStatus()** and **updatePayloadTableAggregateTxtFileName()**. To handle concurrent updates I am using version tag in the mapping file. The problem is that the changes are not getting reflected in the database, whichever method last commit it's changes are getting reflected to solve this issue I am making use of version tag which is long in this case, and if there is version mismatch during update I am handling **StaleStateException** to merge the changes.
But it is not working and I am getting the exception as 
 HHH000346: **Error during managed flush [Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1].**
Please help.

```
public void updateSessionStatus(int jobId, String crcFileName, String crc) {
    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory()
            .openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    PayloadTableDao payloadTableDao = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(PayloadTableDao.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("jobId", jobId));
        ScrollableResults items = crit.scroll();
        while (items.next()) {
            payloadTableDao = (PayloadTableDao) items.get(0);
            if (payloadTableDao.getError() == null) {
                payloadTableDao.setCrcFileName(crcFileName);
                payloadTableDao.setCrc(crc);
            }
            session.saveOrUpdate(payloadTableDao);

            session.update(payloadTableDao);

        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException asd) {
        if (asd instanceof StaleStateException) {
            // session.merge(payloadTableDao);
            handleStale(payloadTableDao);
        }
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        LOGGER.debug(asd.getMessage());
    } finally {
        session.close();

    }
}

public void updatePayloadTableAggregateTxtFileName(int jobId,
        String txtFileName) {
    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory()
            .openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    PayloadTableDao payloadTableDao = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(PayloadTableDao.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("jobId", jobId));
        ScrollableResults items = crit.scroll();

        while (items.next()) {
            payloadTableDao = (PayloadTableDao) items.get(0);
            if (payloadTableDao.getError() == null) {
                payloadTableDao.setTxtFileName(txtFileName);
            }

            session.update(payloadTableDao);

        }
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException asd) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        if (asd instanceof StaleStateException) {
            // session.merge(payloadTableDao);
            handleStale(payloadTableDao);
        }
        LOGGER.debug(asd.getMessage());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}



public synchronized void handleStale(PayloadTableDao payloadTableDao) {
    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory()
            .openSession();
    System.out
            .println("***************************************************************");
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.merge(payloadTableDao);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The catch blocks for your two update methods call rollback/handleStale() in a different ordering - that jumped out at me as possibly unintentional.

Comment: *I am handling StaleStateException to merge the changes*. You can't. At least not that way. The only sensible thing you can do after a hibernate exception is to rollback the transaction and close the session. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#transactions-basics-issues

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the suggestion but my requirement is update both the changes, can you provide with link or resource which shows how to take care such situation.

Comment: You need to rollback the transaction, close the session, and then retry.